# "zsh: illegal hardware instruction python app.py" M1 compability problems

Tags: macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have started building an app that integrates a .h5 file into it. I am also using Tensorflow and I believe this to be the issue. I have removed the Tensorflow part of my project and it loaded up fine, however after reintegrating it, I seem to get the following error message
`"zsh: illegal hardware instruction python app.py"`.
I am working on an M1 chip Mac and am aware of Tensorflow having compatibilty issues with M1 chips which was fixed around 2021. I am also aware that I need to "install native ARM versions of python and all libraries, not Intel ones" but I have tried this to no success.
My specs are:

- Python 3.9.16,
- Tensorflow 2.12.1.

The above were downloaded using pip. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me after trying a bunch of solutions to no avail.

**Step 1** Using pyenv install python version 3.8.5 and set it as your default python version. This tutorial(https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) is helpful for getting pyenv configured properly.

***Step 1.1*** Use this post(https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1446) if you have troubles running pyenv in zsh.

***Step 1.2*** Once you have python version 3.8.5 running which you can check by running python -V which should output:

```
Python 3.8.5
```

***Step 2*** Install virtualenv via pip install virtualenv

***Step 2.1*** Create a virtual environment by running virtualenv ENV

***Step 2.2*** Activate that virtual environment by running source ENV/bin/activate

**Step 3** Install the tensorflow wheel called tensorflow-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl located at this public google drive link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oSipZLnoeQB0Awz8U68KYeCPsULy_dQ7

***Step 3.1*** Assuming you simply installed the wheel to downloads run pip install ~/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl in your activated virtual environment

**Step 4** Type python which will bring up >>>in your terminal and type

```
import tensorflow
```

If there is no 'zsh illegal hardware instruction" error you should be good to go.

Note: The following will also work if you are using Anaconda. You can skip the virtual env stages (if you have a virtual env configured through Conda) and proceed directly to the pip install (steps 3 and later).